# Bg opacity only for color

Tags: css, colors, opacity

Here i have a Background like this

```
background:url(../img/arrow_lch.png) right no-repeat #2e443a;
```

I have to reduce only `bg color(#2e443a) Opacity`, How???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it this way, and edit the last number for opacity:

```
background-color:rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
```

Comment: no problem. if you would vote my answer as correct, when you can, that would be great :)